# .htaccess redirect to subdomain not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have following code in my .htaccess file located in root of site.com:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.com$
RewriteRule ^files(.*)$ http://files.site.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

I want to redirect `site.com/files/path?query` to `files.site.com/path?query`, but for some reason it won't work. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: What does it do instead of working properly? Do you have any other rewrite rules? Does the directory at `site.com/files/` actually exist, and if so, does it have its own .htaccess inside?  Your rules look like they should work as you've defined them.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It does nothing, so the user actually stays at `site.com/files/path?query`. `/files/path` exists and `files` folder actually has it's own .htaccess file. Is that the cause?

Comment: I removed `/files/.htaccess` and it works. But why is it so? Does the `/files/.htaccess` file overwrite `/.htaccess`, or what?

Comment: If the .htaccess inside `/files` has any rewrite rules of its own defined, or even the presence of `RewriteEngine On`, it will replace any rules defined higher in the directory hierarchy.

Comment: I _didn't think_ the mere presence of .htaccess even with no mod_rewrite stuff defined would override any higher rules, but that may be the case if you have none in `/files/.htaccess`

Comment: In fact I did have `RewriteEngine On` inside, although haven't been using mod_rewrite itself, so it was just my fault that I did not remove that. Anyway, thanks for help.