# Going crazy with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

An old question asked, 
"How do I redirect *mydomain.com/blog* to the subdomain *blog.mydomain*? [.htaccess redirect to subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334171/htaccess-redirect-to-subdomain)

Since I am trying to do exactly the same thing, I tried what it said there, but to no avail.

After many variations, I still cannot get it to work, so I tried to zero in on it with some test cases.  (Figuring out what to put as the target of the Rewrite comes later.)

Starting simply and broadly, I put these lines in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule bloggie http://google.com
RewriteRule blog http://bing.com
```

The first one works great.
If I ask for mydomain.com/bloggie/anything it redirects to Google.
It also works with bloggie in the middle of a word.

The second one simply has no effect; no Bing anywhere in sight.
A request for mydomain.com/blog/anything does not redirect.
It either delivers the page (if it exists) or an error (if not).

Then, just for grins, I added this line in front of those two:

```
RewriteRule log http://stackoverflow.com

Now: mydomain.com/log/anything -> stackoverflow
and: mydomain.com/bloggie/anything -> stackoverflow
and: mydomain.com/clog/anything -> stackoverflow
but: mydomain.com/blog/anything -> doesn't go anywhere, same as above
```

What is so magic about "blog" in this case vs. the others?

In case it matters, in this case mydomain.com is an Add-on domain, and
the webserver is Litespeed.

**UPDATE: See my comment below for relevant information.**

Comment: What is the output of `grep -r blog .htaccess /etc/httpd/conf*/*` - (replacing the path with the path to your apache config if relevant)? That is, does the word appear anywhere else in your apache config?

Comment: I found the reason for the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716128/htaccess-redirect-to-subdomain-not-working -- there is another .htaccess file in the subdomain directory, which messes it up. Now the problem is: how to make the two of them work together nicely.

Comment: Problem solved using the OTHER answer in that old question: just use RedirectMatch instead of Rewrite rule and the two .htaccess files happily coexist.